# Azure Device Provisioning Service: Cannot create a group enrollment using a root CA

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

trying to upload a *.cer for an enrollment group...it keeps saying:

Request body validation failed. If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: xxxxxxxxxx

Did someone encounter something like this?

Comment: BTW *.cer is proven to be valid because it is being used somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this out. To upload the certificate successfully it needs to be a Base-64 encoded *.cer and not a DER encoded binary *.cer.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the .CER must be base64.
PEM format which wraps the body with text which is not base64 is also supported.